# What is the minimal value of set $B$?

Tags: elementary-set-theory

For the sets $A$ and $B$ which are different from null set.

$|A| = 3|B|$

$|A-B| = 4|B-A|$

What is the minimal value of set $B$?

Here is my attempt:

$$|A| = 3|B| + 4|B-A| = 12|A|$$

I've found correct answer with wrong way. So, that was even luck.

Comment: How can that be $$|A| = ...= 12|A|$$ if $A$ is not an empty set?

Comment: @JohnWatson That was my bad. However, the right answer seems 12.

Answer (score 1):

Say $|B-A| = x$, then $|A-B| = 4x$, and say $|A\cap B| =y$ then, from first equation we have $$4x+y =3(x+y)\Longrightarrow x=2y$$

So $|B| = x+y = 3y$. Now if $y=0$ then $x=0$ but that can't be since $A$ and $B$ are nonempty, so $y\geq 1$ and so $|B|\geq 3$.

The model with $|B|=3$ is possible: Take $B=\{0,1,2\}$ and $$A=\{0,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10\}$$